# LibGDX actor clickListener

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть два Stage. В одном из них:

```
 private ImageButton imageButton;
 ....
 imageButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            System.out.println("FCK YEAH!");
        }
    });
```

И все отлично работает.
В другом:

```
private Some some;//наследуется от актера
....
some.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){

            System.out.println("CLICKED!");
            };
        }
    });
```

Ничего не работает.

Понимаю, что проблема именно в том, что чего-то не хватает в классе Some. Собственно вопрос: какие именно методы должны быть перегружены для корректной работы? hit()? touchDown()/touchUp()?

Comment: Вообще вариантов много. Возможно Вы не присвоили значения в переменные x, y, width, height актёра.

Answer (score 0):

1) ClickListener'ы актёров работают только если текщий `InputProcesser` это сцена на которой они находятся. 
2) Чтобы они работали также необходимо задать размеры и положение актёра.

Скорее всего что-то из этого у вас не сделано.